Comma in the Signature of a Brief/Email
When writting the signature of a Brief or Email, which one of the following is to be used before the name/sign of the writer, or are both acceptable?

Mit freundlichen Grüßen

or with a comma

Mit freundlichen Grüßen,

Also is this case only for "Mit freundlichen Grüßen", or would it be the same for other signatures(Liebe Grüße etc.) as well?

In German there is no comma after "Mit freundlichen Grüßen", "Liebe Grüße", and other complimentary close phrases.
"Dein(e)" would be written after a phrase like that and just before the name, also without a comma.

Liebe Grüße
Dein Carsten


Mit freundlichen Grüßen
i.A. Meyer


Wir verbleiben mit freundlichen Grüßen
das Team Kundenbetreuung der Schneiderei Schneider

